# Queue in VSC cannot resolve type

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm learning Java in VSC and found odd issue when playing around with `Queues`.
Below code throws `cannot be resolved to a type` error when trying to use `static` variable.

Java I'm using:

```
java 15 2020-09-15
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15+36-1562)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15+36-1562, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Thanks for help!

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class theQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<recordForHuman> market = new LinkedList<>();
        market.add(new recordForHuman("Alex", 21));
    }

    //'record' is not a valid type name; it is a restricted identifier and not allowed as a type identifier in Java 15
    //static record Human(String name, int age){}

    //recordForHuman cannot be resolved to a type
    static recordForHuman Human(String name, int age){}
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense. What do you intend recordForHuman and Human to be?

Comment: I pointed in the comments above. `record Human` throws reserved keyword. `recordForHuman` throws `cannot be resolved to a type`.

Comment: That is the error your asleep seeing.. What I'm asking is what is your expectation of what are those.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but you can use `Record` as a type. We use UpperCammelCase for types/classes and lowerCammelCase for methods/functions and (most) fields/attributes. Also, could you show what is going on in your `Human(String, int)`?

Comment: Don't use Java 15, it is not a supported version. Supported versions are LTS versions like Java 8, 11 and 17, and the latest Java release, Java 20 (which is supported until the release of Java 21, which will also be a LTS version). In addition records were a preview feature in Java 15, so you cannot use the without enabling preview features. Records were were released (no longer in "preview") in Java 16. So, if you want to use records, use Java 17 or Java 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by aled, I was missing entire class.

Below is working solution, still not using `static record` variable but works fine.

Still wonder how to make a use of `record` despite it being a reserved.

```
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.Queue;
    
    public class TheQueue {
        public static void main(String[] args){

        Queue<Person> peers = new LinkedList<>();
        peers.add(new Person("Alex", 1));
        peers.add(new Person("Martin", 4));
        peers.add(new Person("Mary", 3));
        
        System.out.println(peers.size());
        System.out.println(peers.peek());
        System.out.println(peers.poll());
        System.out.println(peers.size());
        System.out.println(peers.peek());
    }

    static class Person {
        String name;
        int key;

        public Person(String name, int key) {
            this.name = name;
            this.key = key;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person[" + 
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    "key='" + key + '\'' +
                    ']';
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your class "theQueue" should have a name starting with an upper case letter. Why did you make Person a nested static class?

Comment: Fixed upper case letter. I should probably move `Person` to a sepaerate file/class.

Answer (score 2):

That is not a static variable deceleration. It seems to define a static method called `Human` that returns a `recordForHuman`. There is no declaration of a class or interface `recordForHuman` in the code shared so we don't know what that is. Note that by Java naming convention a type should start with an uppercase letter and a method with a lower case letter.

`record` is a reserved word since Java 14 so you can not use it for any identifier.

To fix the error create a type with a proper name and use it.

Comment: That is why I replaced `record` with `recordForHuman` and also didn't work. I'll do some more reading and debugging while working on it.

Comment: Did you create a class for it?

Comment: Not yet. fyi - this is the code I'm trying to re-create (47:50); youtube.com/watch?v=8MmMm2-kJV8&list

Comment: Then you should expect the error. You **have** to create types that you use. Note that images and videos must not be used in Stackoverlow for code nor text.

Comment: Ok, got it fixed. Posting solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

If the static Human() is supposed to be a variable, then you need to make an instance like you did with the queue, `Human h = new Human()`,  if it's supposed to be a method, then you need to either create a `recordForHuman` class for the method to return.